# How to properly create a recursion query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
ItemID     ParentID             ItemName
  0          NULL                England
  50         0                   Hampshire county
  401        50                  Southampton
  402        50                  Portsmouth
```

What I want is the following table:

```
ItemID     Level        ItemName                ItemPath
  0          0           England                 England
  50         1           Hampshire county        England\HampshireCounty
  401        2           Southampton             England\HampshireCounty\Southampton
  402        2           Portsmouth              England\HampshireCounty\Portsmouth
```

I've created the following query:

```
WITH tree (A_ItemName, A_ItemId, A_Level, pathstr)
AS (SELECT ItemName, ItemId, 0, 
         CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
     FROM Items 
     WHERE ParentID IS NULL 
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT ItemName, ItemID, t.A_Level + 1, t.pathstr + '/' + V.ItemName
     FROM Items V 
         INNER JOIN tree t 
             ON t.A_ItemId = V.ItemID) 
SELECT SPACE(A_Level) + A_ItemName as A_ItemName, A_ItemId, A_Level, pathstr 
FROM tree 
ORDER BY pathstr, A_ItemId
```

However, I've got an error:

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted
>   before statement completion.

Any idea what I've done wrong?

Comment: Try to append `option ( MaxRecursion 0 )`

Comment: ON t.A_ItemId = V.ItemID  ??

Comment: on Gordon Linoff  correction change `CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX))`  to `CAST(ItemName AS VARCHAR(MAX))`

Comment: @Hamawi thank you very much:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the parent.  I think this does what you want:

```
WITH tree (A_ItemName, A_ItemId, A_Level, pathstr) AS (
      SELECT ItemName, ItemId, 0, CAST(ItemName AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
      FROM Items 
      WHERE ParentID IS NULL 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT ItemName, ItemID, t.A_Level + 1, t.pathstr + '/' + V.ItemName
      FROM Items V INNER JOIN
           tree t 
           ON t.A_ItemId = V.ParentId
     ) 
SELECT SPACE(A_Level) + A_ItemName as A_ItemName, A_ItemId, A_Level, pathstr 
FROM tree 
ORDER BY pathstr, A_ItemId
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the below script for including the parent tag ('England').

```
WITH tree (A_ItemName, A_ItemId, A_Level, pathstr) AS (
      SELECT ItemName, ItemId, 0, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ItemName)
      FROM #t  
      WHERE ParentID IS NULL 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT ItemName, ItemID, t.A_Level + 1, t.pathstr + '/' + V.ItemName
      FROM #t V INNER JOIN
           tree t 
           ON ISNULL(t.A_ItemId,0) = V.ParentId
     ) 
SELECT SPACE(A_Level) + A_ItemName as A_ItemName, A_ItemId, A_Level, pathstr 
FROM tree 
ORDER BY pathstr, A_ItemId
```